# Grouping Records by Key into a single row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am struggling to get the data arranged how i would like.
Essentially i am aiming to track a containers journey measuring time it spends in locations by looking a the times that it enters and leaves these locations

The table i am pulling from is pictured here
[image: #Extract Table containing Data]

My code is below

```
INSERT #EXAMTIME
SELECT
Container_FK
,case when Move_Indicator = '0' then OffChasisTime else null end 
,case when Move_Indicator = '1' then OnChasisTime else null end 
,case when Move_Indicator = '1' then OffChasisTime else null end 
,case when Move_Indicator = '3' then OnChasisTime else null end 
,case when Move_Indicator = '3' then OffChasisTime else null end 
,case when Move_Indicator = '4' then OnChasisTime else null end 
FROM #EXTRACT
```

And here is the output table
[image: Resultant Table]

As you can see the data is each on its own row, I want to group by Container_FK so that each Entry has the whole journey

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select Container_FK,
       max(case when Move_Indicator = '0' then OffChasisTime else null end),
       max(case when Move_Indicator = '1' then OnChasisTime else null end),
       max(case when Move_Indicator = '1' then OffChasisTime else null end),
       max(case when Move_Indicator = '3' then OnChasisTime else null end),
       max(case when Move_Indicator = '3' then OffChasisTime else null end),
       max(case when Move_Indicator = '4' then OnChasisTime else null end)
from #EXTRACT
group by Container_FK;
```

Note that `else null` is redundant, so it is just wasted typing.  Also, if `Move_Indicator` is a number, then remove the double quotes around the constants.  Numbers should be compared to numbers, not strings.

Comment: The null Value is there currently as some records are incomplete so not all Containers will have data to fill all columns. This is recording data from a small trial snapshot but will be used later in a production capacity where this shouldnt occur. It worked though many thanks, i did not know you could use the max aggregate function as a proxy to allow a group by thats a really useful tip! The integer thing is something i will bear in mind in future.